# "internal" port forwarding from the internet to hamachi server

Tags: windows-7, networking, port-forwarding

I use Hamachi and I have a server that binds onto a port with my Hamachi IP. 
However, I would like this server to be accessible via the Internet so I was thinking I would forward my ports to my desktop then run some sort of internal tool that then marshes the data to the server bound on the Hamachi port.

I need to continue running this server on Hamachi.

I use Windows 7 x64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you have your server process only binding to one IP address and port? Just have it bind to its standard port on "any" address, and then do normal NAT port forwarding to it.